# Imprimir elegantemente

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero saber cómo debo imprimir los datos en pantalla para que me salga de una manera "elegante", es decir que cada columna se muestre verticalmente ordenada.  Estoy usando el siguiente método:

```
print("%s: %12i %25.2f "%(string,valor_int,valor_float))
```

[image: Problema al imprimir]

Comment: Amigo te comporta este [link](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/inputoutput.html) creo que podrás encontrar buena información de como generar espacios, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre en tu ejemplo, es que la "columna" correspondiente a `string` no está correctamente alineada, por lo que desfasa toda la salida. Lo que puedes hacer es algo así:

```
print("%-20s: %12i %25.2f "%(string,valor_int,valor_float))
```

Básicamente estamos armando las opciones de formateo de cada valor, la de los números ya la habías hecho tú, la de la cadena se lee de la siguiente forma: `-` para alineación a izquierda, `20s` define que la salida será una cadena de una longitud mínima de 20 caracteres. Esto soluciona en parte el problema, con cadenas de hasta 20 caracteres funcionará bien, pero al ser la longitud mínima, con cadenas más largas tendremos un problema:

```
string= "Esta es una prueba de una cadena bien larga"
valor_int = 15
valor_float = 236.56

print("--------------------- ------------ -------------------------")
print("%-20s: %12i %25.2f "%(string,valor_int,valor_float))
```

Salida:

```
--------------------- ------------ -------------------------
Esta es una prueba de una cadena bien larga:           15                    236.56
```

La opción es forzar un recorte de la cadena a 20 caracteres usando un "slice" así: `string[0:20]`:

```
print("--------------------- ------------ -------------------------")
print("%-20s: %12i %25.2f "%(string[0:20],valor_int,valor_float))
```

Ahora sí la salida es más "elegante":

```
--------------------- ------------ -------------------------
Esta es una prueba d:           15                    236.56
```

Esta forma de formatear los datos esta heredada de Python 2x, si bien se mantiene en la nuevas versiones, creo que es recomendable decirte que veas las nuevas opciones que te ofrece el lenguaje por medio de la función `format()`: [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). Es bastante sencillo para adaptarse, tu ejemplo podría quedar algo así:

```
print("{:<20s}: {:12} {:25.2f} ".format(cadena[0:20],valor_int,valor_float))
```

Por otro lado si eventualmente buscas una forma más sencilla de manejar una salida tabular te recomiendo el módulo [`tabulate`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate)